# Query Firebase Database with two between conditions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm wondering if it's possible to return a list of values from my Firebase database where each element satisfies two conditions.

For example, if my database looked like this:

```
MYAPP
|_______________items
|                   |_____OshwYF72Jhd9bUw56W7d
|                   |                   |
|                   |                   |__item_name:"plank_5"
|                   |                   |__length:"120"            
|                   |                   |__width:"50"             
|                   |                            
|                   |_____KbHy4293dYgVtT9pdoW
|                   |_____PS8tgw53SnO892Jhweh
|                   |_____Gicuwy8r23ndoijdakr
|
|___customers
```

And I want to query the database for the `item_name` of every item that has a length of between 100-150 and a width of between 30-70, is there a way for me to do this with a Firebase query?

I've read the answers here: [Query based on multiple where clauses in firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase) but that doesn't deal with multiple `between`/`range` clauses, which is what I would need in the above scenario.

I saw this plugin in another answer: https://github.com/davideast/Querybase but the `where` clause doesn't seem to take a range of values. For example:

```
const queriedDbRef = querybaseRef
  .where({
    length: (between 100-150),
    width: (between 30-70)
  });
```

Is such a query even possible? Or will I have to get all items matching one condition, and then apply the second condition client-side, using Javascript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Firebase Database query can only order/filter on one property. That's a hard limit that is not likely to change in the near future.

In **some** cases it is possible to combine multiple values into a single property, such my answer you linked or in QueryBase. But in those cases as you found, you can only perform a relative/range query on a single of those values: i.e. the last one.

The only case where someone (to my knowing) has ever implemented multi-value range querying is in GeoFire, where we combine the longitude and latitude of a location into a so-called [GeoHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). I highly recommend reading more about geohashes, because they do something quite unique: combine two numerical values, into a single string value that allows ordering and filtering on its numeric components.

From looking at the two values you want to combine (length and width), it **might** be possible to create a similar composite string from them. But requires that you find a way to combine the two values for your use-case. The simplest possible way I can think if would be to store the *area*, so length * width:

```
{
  items: {
    "OshwYF72Jhd9bUw56W7d": {
      item_name:"plank_5",
      length: 120, // you store length and width as strings, please fix that
      width: 50,
      area: 6000
    }
  }
}
```

That way you can filter for items with an area between 3000 (100x30) and 10500 (70x150):

```
var query = ref.orderBy("area").startAt(3000).endAt(10500);
```

This query will match too many items, so you will have to perform some extra filtering client-side to reject the mismatches (Geofire does the same btw):

```
query.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
  var item = snapshot.val();
  if (item.length >= 100 && item.length <= 150
      && item.width >= 30 && item.width <= 70) {
    // TODO: do something with the item
  }
});
```

Comment: This is really interesting @frank-van-puffelen ! Thanks for your detailed answer. I've taken your advice and have been trying to learn geoFire over the last day, I've had a little problem with returning IDs from a geoFire query though, and was wondering if you could take a look at it over here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275999/firebase-geofire-how-to-return-an-array-of-ids-within-a-range Thanks again for this!

Comment: I mostly used Geofire as an example of how seemingly impossible things are possible if you think outside of the box and are willing to spend to effort. I for one would never have thought of combining longitude and latitude in a single string in such a way that they remain sortable. Luckily length*width was slightly easier to calculate. :-)