# How to implement BETWEEN Sql query in Firebase?

Tags: android, sql, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a android Firebase project. I need help in implementing this sql query in Firebase real-time database.

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE price BETWEEN $min AND $max;
```

Comment: Might want to look at this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228445/query-firebase-database-with-two-between-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's [good documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#ordering-by-a-specified-child-key) on how to do firebase queries as well as [apply them to ranges](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#range-queries).

Something like:

```java
FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("table");

Query query = ref.orderByChild("price").startAt(min).endAt(max);
```

Then you add the appropriate listener for what you are trying to do. (e.g. a [`ValueEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener) or a [`ChildEventListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) via `addValueEventListener` or `addChildEventListener` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method

```js
new Firebase("https://examples-sql-queries.firebaseio.com/messages")
    .startAt(startTime)
    .endAt(endTime)
    .once('value', function(snap) {
       console.log('messages in range', snap.val());
    });
```

Comment: FYI, This appears to be an answer for javascript, but the question is about Android.